# Updating User Data from Magento to Odoo

Tags: php, odoo, magento-1.9

I'm using Odoo as my **CRM** & **Magento** as my web application. I've been able to Insert data correctly in Odoo. However, While i was trying to update one of existing data on Odoo with one of my field as reference from magento it didn't update but when i used the Odoo generated ID i was able to update my data. I've already created field in Odoo which bears the same ID i have in my magento database & I want to update it based on magento's ID.

Here's the snippet of my Code

```
$data = array("userID"=>$userID, "Address"=>$user_address);
$models->execute_kw($db, $uid, $password, 'res.partner', 'write',
                array(array(1258), array($data)));
```

Comment: #1 what is the type of userID(is it a relation field 12m or m2x) #2 if YES then  is it present in the relation model at ODOO end  #3 MODEL res.partner HAVE ID 1258 OR NOT

Comment: @Prakash User ID is a simple field like you can say an additional custom field made in partner model. No it doesn't have that ID 1258 because this is the increment ID generated by Magento and on the basis of magento generated ID i want to update fields in ODOO